# Every weak neighborhood of $0$ contains a finite co-dimensional subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, weak-topology

I'm trying to prove a statement mentioned in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/390610/99469) answer, i.e.,

> In an infinite dimensional normed space $(E, |\cdot|)$, every weak neighborhood of $0$ contains a finite co-dimensional subspace.

Could you please have a check on my below attempt?

---

Let $X$ be a neighborhood of $0\in E$ in the weak topology $\sigma(E, E^*)$. By construction of $\sigma(E, E^*)$, there are $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in E^*$ and $\varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_n >0$ such that
$$
X \supseteq U:=\{x\in E \mid \forall k = 1, \ldots,n: |\langle f_k, x \rangle| < \varepsilon_k\}.
$$

Consider the continuous linear map
$$
T:E \to \mathbb R^n, x \mapsto \big ( \langle f_1, x \rangle, \ldots, \langle f_n, x \rangle \big ).
$$

By first isomorphism theorem for rings, $E/ \ker T \cong R(T)$ where $R(T)$ is the range of $T$. On the other hand, $\dim R(T) \le n$ and
$$
\ker T = \bigcap_{k=1}^n \ker f_k \subset U.
$$

The claim then follows.

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you so much for your verification!